# In python 3.5, how do I compare a string variable with part of another string?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm currently learning Python and I have a question which I cannot find the answer too, currently I am trying to take a string variable given from the user and comparing it to part of another string. I want something like this:

> Program: The given sentence is "I like chemistry", enter a word in the
>   sentence given.
>
> User: like
>
> Program: Your word is in the sentence.

I can only seem to make a program using the `if` function and `==` but this only seems to recognize that the two strings are similar if I type the full sentence given by the program.

From the some of the answers I have changed my program to but there seems to be an error I cannot find.

```
sentence=("I like chemistry")
print("The given sentence is: ",sentence)
word=input("Give a word in the sentence: ").upper
while word not in sentence:
    word=input("Give a valid word in the sentence: ")
if word in sentence:
    print("valid")
```

Comment: Does it need to be a *word*, or can any substring match?

Comment: You want to test whether the word is **in** the sentence. Have you tried `if word in sentence`?

Comment: Any word, as in the user can type in "like" for the given sentence and the program would tell you it is a match.

Comment: "I can only seem to make a program using" do you mean that that's the only thing you can think of, or is the assignment (?) restricted to using those operations?

Comment: Only thing I can think of.

Comment: Part of programming is to understand *all* of the constraints of a problem. For example in this one, should a search for "lick" also match "clicked"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `in` together with `split`:

```
>>> s = "I like chemistry"
>>> words = s.split()
>>> "like" in words
True
>>> "hate" in words
False
```

The difference between this approach vs. using `in` against the non-split string is like this:

```
>>> "mist" in s
True
>>> "mist" in words
False
```

If you want arbitrary substrings then use simply `w in s` but is you want white-space delimited words then use `w in words`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if word in sentence:
```

Welcome to the wonderful world of python.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you use `if substring in string: ...`.

Example:

```
mystring = "I like chemistry"
if "like" in mystring:
    print("Word is in sentence")
else:
    print("Word is not in sentence")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking it as finding a substring, think it as checking membership. And all sequence types in Python expose the same interface for that purpose. Say `s` is a sequence, i.e `str`, `list`, `tuple` and to see if `m` is in `s`,

```
>>> m in s # => bool :: True | False
```

The same `in` operator works for `dict` keys and `set` as well, though they are not sequences.